# Can I get the ID of a post on a facebook wall after it led to my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Imagine 5 people shared my website on their walls. Now each post has a different post ID. Let's say some friend clicks 1 of these 5 posts and is directed to my website. 
Can I use the graph API on my website to get the ID of the post that led the visitor to my website? It would be even better if I could get the ID of the person that posted the link my visitor clicked on.

I use the following code to get ID and name of the person that's visiting my website and it seems like I can't go any deeper:

`FB.api(    '/me', {fields: 'last_name'},
            function (response) {});`

I want to know where the visitor is coming from because I'm trying to create a personalized experience for the people that share my website.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just share unique links. So when someone click the link you know which link that was

Comment: That's a way to work around the issue but in my case not acceptable. I need the link to be the default one, free of additional parameters in the URL

Comment: _“It would be even better if I could get the ID of the person that posted the link my visitor clicked on”_ - yeah, wouldn’t so many things in this world be so much better, if only that nasty little thing called privacy did not exist ...

Comment: Isn't it time we give up on privacy for the sovereign good?

Comment: Just because you need something doesn't mean it exists. There is no way to do it and that is why I suggested one workaround for you

Comment: A workaround is not what my client asked for. Thanks for the suggestion tho. I'm doing research and asked this question here because I couldn't find clear answers to it in the FB documentation but maybe I'v just searched in the wrong places or overlooked smth. How come you know that there's no way to do it?